# Why do Quaternions have four variables?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The official documentation for the Unity Engine doesn't contain this, and I'm not far enough into my math/physics studies to have come across a Quaternion, but I understand it has to do with rotation. What I don't understand is why Quaternions have four variables, w,x,y,z, when there are only three axis of rotation in Unity.

Comment: The trick is that we require `w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1`, so there are four variables minus one equation which gives the expected three degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A quaternion is basically an axis in 3D space with a angle of rotation around the axis. Four values make up a quaternion, namely x, y, z and w. Three of the values are used to represent the axis in vector format, and the forth value would be the angle of rotation around the axis."

http://www.real3dtutorials.com/tut00011.php

So you could think of it as the rotation of the rotation, in simple terms!

Like Hellium noted in the comments below; Unity recommends that you do not fiddle with Quaternions directly if don't know exactly what you're doing. Like Hellium also points out, whatever you want to accomplish, you probably want to use the static methods of the [Quaternion class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html). They are very useful and easy to use and can accomplish most things you want to do with rotations.

Comment: With such definition, a novice would want to set the individual values of a Quaternion by hand, **which is not recommended at all**, unless, you **really know** what you are doing. Instead, use the provided static functions of the Quaternion class : Quaternion.LookRotation, Quaternion.Angle, Quaternion.Euler, Quaternion.Slerp, Quaternion.FromToRotation, ....

Comment: That is very true, and probably important to point out. Whatever you want to do, you will probably want to use the static methods anyway. I'll update the answer with that, good point!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score -1):

WXYZ is a unit vector in 4 dimensional space. It uses the "trick" that complex number math can be used to calculate rotations i.e. W + Xi + Yj + Zk. The four numbers kind of represent an axis and a rotation around that axis but not exactly:

x, y, z: rotation axis - needs to be a unit vector
angle: rotation around axis

W = cos(angle / 2)
X = sin(angle / 2) * x
Y = sin(angle / 2) * y
Z = sin(angle / 2) * z