# How to get an objects rotation in degrees? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

When I run this:
Debug.Log(playerCenter.transform.rotation);
It gives a result that has four values. Each of those values are between -1 and 1. How do I just get the x y and z values in degrees.

Also what is the fourth value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transform.rotation not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56610816/1092820)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `playerCenter.transform.rotation.eulerAngle`? or maybe `playerCenter.transform.eulerAngle`. Also about the fourth value, are you refering to   the fourth parameter of `Quaternion`? e.g. `Quaternion (float x, float y, float z, float w)`?

Comment: Adding eulerAngles worked. Thanks! Debug.Log(playerCenter.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html), transform.rotation returns a Quaternion that is normalized. Also a quaternion returns 4 values. The [first value you](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-w.html) are getting is the rotation around the other vector(the other 3 values). [As this stackoverflow post perfectly says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285413/why-do-quaternions-have-four-variables), `So you could think of it as the rotation of the rotation, in simple terms!`